# Magento wysiwyg editor not working and showing blank image popup

Tags: magento-1.9, php, wysiwyg

I have implement wysiwyg text editor in magento for my custom module. On my local machine it is working properly.

When I upload my code on live server then wysiwyg showing blank image popup.
Please find attached screenshot of the error which I am getting.

Any one can please advice.[image]

Comment: Have you flushed the cache? Can you check the logs to see if there is some error there (under var/log/)? Also check the firebug console for errors.

Comment: No error in logs. Although I am getting an error in firebug console

Blocked loading mixed active content "http://domainname/index.php/admin/cms_wysiwyg_images/index/target_element_id/webcontent/store/undefined/type/image/?isAjax=true"

Comment: Cache also clear. Folder permission for wysiwyg is also set to 777.

Comment: Did you already try to turn on `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` in `index.php`?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your urls from http to https in the ajax request to fix the "Blocked loading mixed active content".

> What is Mixed Content?
>   When a user visits a page served over HTTP, their connection is open for eavesdropping and man-in-the-middle (MITM) attacks. When a user visits a page served over HTTPS, their connection with the web server is authenticated and encrypted with SSL and hence safeguarded from eavesdroppers and MITM attacks.
>
> However, if an HTTPS page includes HTTP content, the HTTP portion can be read or modified by attackers, even though the main page is served over HTTPS. When an HTTPS page has HTTP content, we call that content “mixed”. The webpage that the user is visiting is only partially encrypted, since some of the content is retrieved unencrypted over HTTP. The Mixed Content Blocker blocks certain HTTP requests on HTTPS pages.

Credit goes to this answer, check it for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18251129/1016425

Comment: @OP You might also want to google "javascript same origin policy"